# The type initializer logger extension throw an exception

Tags: c#, exception, .net-core

I am making an .NET Core application and I wanted to start an app but it says at this line of code:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
```

...
it says this error:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcCoreLoggerExtensions' threw an exception.'
```

...
that is something new and I never seen that before while starting an application. How can I fix it?

... Inner exception is:

```
Method not found: 'System.Action`4<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger,!!0,!!1,System.Exception> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerMessage.Define(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventId, System.String, Boolean)'.
```

Main.cs

```
 public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

...

.NET Core 6.0 is the latest version ... Identity is included into application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The type initializer for 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcCoreLoggerExtensions' threw an exception.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68848170/the-type-initializer-for-microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-mvccoreloggerextensions-thre)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. For the experiment, I created a new project and added the latest version of Microsoft.Extensions.Logging to it (currently 6.0.0-preview.7.21377.19). The project crashes with the same error as yours.
The problem is that there is no four-argument overload in [LoggerMessage.Define](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loggermessage.define?view=dotnet-plat-ext-%206.0). Downgrading the package to version 6.0.0-preview.6.21352.12 helped me.